# What is the correct typing for this case (subclassed method)?

Tags: python, python-typing

I can't get the following type hint right. Could you please help?

```
# example edited to make simpler (was async)
from typing import Any, Callable, ClassVar

class Base:
    def n_a(self) -> str:
        return 'N/A'

    meth1: ClassVar[Callable[[Base], str]] = n_a 
    # also meth2, meth3, ...

class Subclass(Base):
    def meth1(self) -> str:  # <-- line 11
        return 'yes'
```

the error is:

```
test.py:11: error: Signature of "meth1" incompatible with supertype "Base"  [override]
test.py:11: note:      Superclass:
test.py:11: note:          def (Base, /) -> str
test.py:11: note:      Subclass:
test.py:11: note:          def meth1(self) -> str
```

The problem is probably here:

```
ClassVar[Callable[[Base], str]]
                  ^^^^^^
```

because this is accepted without errors:

```
 ClassVar[Callable[..., str]]
```

---

Update: attempt to use `Self` as suggested in the comments:

```
test-self.py:11: error: Signature of "meth1" incompatible with supertype "Base"  [override]
test-self.py:11: note:      Superclass:
test-self.py:11: note:          def (Self, /) -> str
test-self.py:11: note:      Subclass:
test-self.py:11: note:          def meth1(self) -> str
```

Comment: In Python 3.11 I think this is handled by using the new `Self` form from `typing` module. see PEP 673.  Unfortunately I don't have the opportunity to investigate and write up a full answer right nowa

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with `async` functions per se. And it also occurs, if you omit the type annotation for `meth1` entirely. That was my first instinct because every type checker should infer the type automatically, when you assign `n_a` to it. I think I boiled it down to [**this**](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=e1ba8fe5134520407f07c546168388d1). Maybe I am crazy, but it seems strange that overriding `a` works, but `b` does not. Unless someone else here figures out what we are doing wrong, this may be worth a question at the mypy issue tracker.

Comment: The problem is that `line_11` is being interpreted as an instance method, not a function. When it tries to match `Subclass.meth1` to `Base.meth1`, mypy thinks that `Base.meth1` has 2 arguments: an implicit `self`, then `Base`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Yes, async does not play a role. I have edited the question and removed the async definitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following tweak passes MyPy, but I may be missing some caveat. I just gave the method a unique name and then assigned it to the class variable `meth1`

```
class Subclass(Base):
    async def foo(self) -> str:  # <-- line 11
        return 'yes'

    meth1 = foo
```

I ran a test including some info from `typing_extensions.reveal_type` and it looked to be as expected:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import asyncio
from typing import Any, Callable, Coroutine, ClassVar
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

class Base:
    async def n_a(self) -> str:
        return 'N/A'

    meth1: ClassVar[Callable[[Base], Coroutine[Any, Any, str]]] = n_a
    # also meth2, meth3, ...

class Subclass(Base):
    async def foo(self) -> str:  # <-- line 11
        return 'yes'

    meth1 = foo

# The comments I added here are informational messages from the ErrorLens extension
reveal_type(Base.meth1)  #Type of "Base.meth1" is "(Base) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, str]"
reveal_type(Subclass.foo) #Type of "Subclass.foo" is "(self: Subclass) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, str]"
reveal_type(Subclass.meth1) #Type of "Subclass.meth1" is "(Base) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, str]"

async def get_results(BaseObj: Base, SubObj: Subclass):
    return (await BaseObj.meth1(), await SubObj.foo(), await SubObj.meth1())

B = Base()
S = Subclass()
reveal_type(B.meth1) # Type of "B.meth1" is "() -> Coroutine[Any, Any, str]"
reveal_type(S.foo)   # Type of "S.foo" is "() -> Coroutine[Any, Any, str]"
reveal_type(S.meth1) # Type of "S.meth1" is "() -> Coroutine[Any, Any, str]"
res = asyncio.run(get_results(B, S))
print(f"{res[0]}\n{res[1]}\n{res[2]}")
```

Output:

```
Runtime type is 'function'
Runtime type is 'function'
Runtime type is 'function'
Runtime type is 'method'  
Runtime type is 'method'  
Runtime type is 'method'
N/A
yes
yes
```

MyPy reveals slightly different info from the reveal_types calls, giving both Subclass.foo and Subclass.meth1 identical signatures while Error Lens said they were different.  Not sure if that's a bug in the Error Lens extension or not:

```
$ mypy typingtests.py
typingtests.py:22: note: Revealed type is "def (typingtests.Base) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
typingtests.py:23: note: Revealed type is "def (self: typingtests.Subclass) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
typingtests.py:24: note: Revealed type is "def (self: typingtests.Subclass) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
typingtests.py:32: note: Revealed type is "def () -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
typingtests.py:33: note: Revealed type is "def () -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
typingtests.py:34: note: Revealed type is "def () -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.str]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. According to responses an issue with the mypy looks quite possible.